# getting error in inserting logout button in masterpage in asp.net c#

Tags: c#-4.0, logout

Control 'ctl00_logout' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

im facing this problem while i run this code.

```
<div align="center">
             <asp:Button ID="logout" runat="server" Text="Logout" Visible="false" 
                 onclick="logout_Click" />
            </div>
```

and my codebehind file code is:

```
protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("~/Home Page.aspx");
}
```

---

if i put form tag inside the master page then also i'm getting error ......please give a solution thank u...

Answer (score 0):

Every content you have in yout `MasterPage` must be wrapped in a `<form runat="server">` tag - opening tag will be just after `<body>` tag, and the form closing tag just befory `</body>`